# Why would initially requested HTML be different than what is shown to the user and in inspect element?

Tags: javascript, html

There seems to be something fundamental here i'm missing and I'd like to get it cleared up so sorry if this seems low level.

As an example, I would like to grab the shipping information from a specific tracked package on UPS's website (i.e. Shipment status, expected date info like that). So, I look at their URL format and insert my tracking number where applicable. In the network section of my browsers development tools I see an initial request that returns a bunch of HTML, however, this HTML looks vastly different than what I'm seeing on my end as a user as well as what is shown in inspect element.

Essentially what I'm asking is, why would this returned HTML be different? and what would be the best way of getting the "correct" html when i'm technically getting back the same HTML my browser is using initially when I load up the website myself?  In this case I'm using XMLHttpRequest.

[image that shows what's visible to the user and what's returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59jDZ.png)

Here you can see how different the two are, not just due to CSS. In this case the returned html is missing all tracking and shipping info.

Any additional resources would be helpful :)

Comment: check chrome console. seem like css and js file is missing or not foud

Comment: Look at your network tab *again*. And look at what happens when the tracking page loads--notice how there's a spinner and no content? Look at the `GetStatus` request and response.

Comment: i think they preloaded a page(DOm) so they don't have fetch it again

Comment: @aviboy2006 No, the OP is previewing the main page's HTML.

Comment: @KALITA That's the HTML of the page; it's not being "pre-loaded", that's the page's HTML.

Comment: @Dave Newton After looking at GetStatus it shows all of the info I need :) I think I'm understanding why that's happening now that you've pointed it out. I just need to figure out how I would go about accessing it.